# quickfixj message factory produces bad type on operand stack using qf 1.6.0 and java 1.8.0_45

Tags: quickfix, quickfixj

```
Jun 18, 2015 3:26:12 PM quickfix.mina.AbstractIoHandler exceptionCaught
SEVERE: java.lang.VerifyError: Bad type on operand stack
Exception Details:
  Location:
    quickfix/fix44/Quote.get(Lquickfix/field/SettlType;)Lquickfix/field/SettlType; @2: invokevirtual
  Reason:
    Type 'quickfix/field/SettlType' (current frame, stack[1]) is not assignable to 'quickfix/CharField'
  Current Frame:
    bci: @2
    flags: { }
    locals: { 'quickfix/fix44/Quote', 'quickfix/field/SettlType' }
    stack: { 'quickfix/fix44/Quote', 'quickfix/field/SettlType' }
  Bytecode:
    0x0000000: 2a2b b600 8257 2bb0
```

Is there a way to handle this error without rebuilding quickFIXJ?

Comment: I get the same error using java JRE 1.7

Comment: If you don't get an answer here, you may want to join the QF/j mailing list and ask there.

Comment: @Grant Birchmeier, this is the stack trace:   `at quickfix.fix44.MessageFactory.create(MessageFactory.java:103)
 at quickfix.DefaultMessageFactory.create(DefaultMessageFactory.java:133)
 at quickfix.MessageUtils.parse(MessageUtils.java:145)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the quickfix mailing lists, [it says](http://sourceforge.net/p/quickfixj/mailman/message/32807121/) that `this is a currently unresolved problem with the 1.6.0-SNAPSHOT version of QF/J. Maybe we will treat all fields with different data types throughout the FIX versions simply as StringField in any case. But this has not been finalized yet.`

I solved the problem by returning to Quickfix 1.5.2

Answer (score 1):

I got the same issue with 1.6.0_1, and resolved with 1.6.4_1.