# apache.servicemix.bundles.quickfix - Attempting to create standalone NewOrderSingle object throws exception

Tags: java, quickfix, fix-protocol, quickfixj

I am attempting to write a class for converting domain POJO's into QuickFixJ messages. When I try to create a new order message as so:

```
quickfix.fix44.NewOrderSingle order = new quickfix.fix44.NewOrderSingle();
```

The following exception is thrown in the logs:

```
Exception Details:
Location:
  quickfix/fix44/NewOrderSingle.get(Lquickfix/field/SettlType;)Lquickfix/field/SettlType; @2: invokevirtual
Reason:
Type 'quickfix/field/SettlType' (current frame, stack[1]) is not assignable to 'quickfix/CharField'
Current Frame:
  bci: @2
  flags: { }
  locals: { 'quickfix/fix44/NewOrderSingle', 'quickfix/field/SettlType' }
  stack: { 'quickfix/fix44/NewOrderSingle', 'quickfix/field/SettlType' }
Bytecode:
  0000000: 2a2b b600 3057 2bb0
```

It seems this error happens when attempting to merge two versions of Fix Message Fields together but as far as I know I am not doing this. I am using the same code as found in the [QuickFixJ unit tests](https://github.com/quickfix-j/quickfixj/blob/master/quickfixj-core/src/test/java/quickfix/MessageTest.java) A variation of the same code works in [this example](http://www.dailyfx.com/forex_forum/fix-api-support/64877-quickfix-java-example.html), it is after a connection is applied through the initiator object. I am using the apache.servicemix.bundles.quickfix instead of the QuickFix-all.jar because it contains some fields i need to add to other messages.

I am unsure why I am not able to call a simple constructor of an object. The constructor in the jar is as follows:

```
public NewOrderSingle()
{
   getHeader().setField(new MsgType("D"));
}
```

Is there another possible cause for this error I havent thought of? I am stumped

Comment: This could be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29967804/quickfix-j-mixing-two-different-versions

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I had checked out this question earlier. It is the same error, but I am not trying to merge two FIX message versions together. All I am trying to do is create an object of type fix44.message but I cant call the constructor without this error being thrown. I have imported the required dependencies from the sample project which is working. I just cant figure out what is causing the exception

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had this problem and had to revert to QuickFIX 1.5.2

[quickfixj message factory produces bad type on operand stack using qf 1.6.0 and java 1.8.0_45](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30918449/quickfixj-message-factory-produces-bad-type-on-operand-stack-using-qf-1-6-0-and)

It's a known issue according to the user group. See the attached question...